How can I put a LazyColumn in a Swipeable composable and have it swipe when the column is at the top
I'm building an Android launcher using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, and I want to implement an app drawer similar to the Pixel Launcher. The drawer slides up using a LazyColumn to list the apps. I want the LazyColumn to allow scrolling, but if the user is at the top of the list, I want the swipe down gesture to close the drawer instead of bouncing the list.
The issue I'm facing is that the LazyColumn's scroll behavior is overriding the .swipeable() modifier on the Box. When the user is at the top of the LazyColumn, I want the swipe down gesture to close the drawer. However, the list just bounces instead of triggering the swipe action.
Here’s a minimal reproducible example of my current code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalWearMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun SwipeableHome() {
    val appDrawSize = 1000.dp
    val swipeableState = rememberSwipeableState(1)
    val sizePx = with(LocalDensity.current) { appDrawSize.toPx() }
    val anchors = mapOf(0f to 0, sizePx to 1) // Maps anchor points (in px) to states
    val appsListScrollState = rememberLazyListState()

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .swipeable(
                state = swipeableState,
                anchors = anchors,
                thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.3f) },
                orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                enabled = isAppDrawAtTop.value
            )
    ) {
        Text("Home")
        AppsList()
    }
}

@Composable
fun AppsList() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .offset { IntOffset(0, swipeableState.offset.value.roundToInt()) }
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            state = appsListScrollState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset { IntOffset(0, swipeableState.offset.value.roundToInt()) }
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            items(sortedInstalledApps) { app ->
               AppsListItem(app)
            }
        }
    }
}

I’ve tried using nestedScroll to detect when the user is swiping at the top of the list and disable the LazyColumn scrolling, but this results in requiring two swipes: the first swipe disables the scrolling, and the second closes the drawer.
Is there a better way to handle this interaction so that a swipe down at the top of the list closes the drawer seamlessly?

What I've Tried:
Here’s an example of my nested scroll attempt, which requires two swipes to close the draw:
val isAppDrawAtTop = remember {
    derivedStateOf { appsListScrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0 && appsListScrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset == 0 }
}
LazyColumn(
    state = appsListScrollState,
    modifier = Modifier
        .offset { IntOffset(0, swipeableState.offset.value.roundToInt()) }
        .fillMaxSize()
        .nestedScroll(remember {
            object : androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection {
                override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                    return if (available.y > 0 && isAppDrawAtTop.value) {
                        shouldScroll.value = false
                        Offset.Zero
                    } else {
                        shouldScroll.value = true
                        super.onPreScroll(available, source)
                    }
                }
            }
        }),
    userScrollEnabled = shouldScroll.value
) {
    items(sortedInstalledApps) { app ->
        SwipeAppsListItem(app)
    }
}


Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
UPDATE:
I did it using a horizontalPager

You are on the right path with the nested scroll, but it will be more complex than what you did. I think that the best thing you can do is taking a look at the BottomSheetScaffold from material3 which can do that and you can pretty much copy their code.

Thanks! I'll check that out.

@JanBína I've tried to use the bottomSheet, is there any way to hide the bar at the top with the handle or at least change the colour of the handle and background as I'm finding the handle goes behind the camera when it's fully opened, I also want to use a custom background but the background behind the handle wont change colour. Thanks for your comment this has pointed me in the right direction
